# How can I get a block to print complicated divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css, position, block, positioning

I have a block that prints out complicated divs with many line breaks, and I would like for it to print horizontally. For simplicity, I'm just trying it with this code:

**html**

```
<div id="body">
  <% Model.each do |f| %>
    <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#body {
  #item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Apparently, `display: inline;` makes the next item start at the point the last item ends. So right now, it prints out like this:

```
This is
a test. This is
  a test. This is
    a test.
```

But I would like the next item to always start at the top of the container, like this:

```
This is     This is     This is
a test.     a test.     a test.
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `display: inline-block` should help.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!

Comment: @emmanuel If you added it as an answer, I could accept it and give you reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `display` from `inline` to `inline-block` should help.

```
#body {
  #item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexible boxes:

```css
#body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap; /* default value */
}
```

This way the children will be displayed horizontally, without wrapping, even if that means that there will be overflow.

```css
#body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
  <div id="item">This is <br> a test.</div>
</div>
```